# CAN I USE Basic Authentication to access SharePoint 2010 from JAVA with GET REST request?

Tags: java, rest, authentication, sharepoint-2010, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to get a list of data from SharePoint 2010 using REST request but I obtain this exception:

**[err] java.io.IOException: Unauthorized**

My code is:

```
public static String httpGet(String urlStr) throws IOException {

      URL url = new URL(urlStr);          
      String domain = "theuserdomain"; 
      String username ="myusername";
      String password = "mypassword";
      String credentials = domain+"\\"+username + ":" + password;
      String encoding = new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(credentials.getBytes());

      HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
      conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
      conn.connect();

      if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new IOException(conn.getResponseMessage());
      }

      // Buffer the result into a string
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(
          new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
      StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
      String line;
      while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
      }
      rd.close();

      conn.disconnect();
      return sb.toString();
    }
```

I think that my problem is that I don't set the user domain correctly...how can I set it on my request?

Comment: How do you fill out the dialog box of the browser when you are not authenticated? And does this work with Firefox and Chrome or only with Internet Explorer. If no, maybe SharePoint doesn't use Basic Authentication but something like NTLM Chalenge/Response ...

Comment: I've tried with Firefox, Explorer and Chrome and I can see the response. In the browser authentication form I wrote: USERNAME:  theuserdomain\myusername   PASSWORD: mypassword     and it works! Is it Basic Authentication right?

Comment: You could trace the outgoing/incoming traffic e.g. in Chrome Web-Developer or FireFox Firebug and compare the headers set by the browsers with yours.

Comment: With Chrome: Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,/;q=0.‌​8 Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4 Authorization:NTLM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RESOLVED using NTLM Authentication:

```
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(webPage);

        NTCredentials credentials = new NTCredentials(username, password, workstation, domain);


        httpClient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(server,port), credentials);

        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);
```